# Adding vrf interface to a network namespace

Tags: linux-networking, network-namespace

I am trying to add a VRF interface to a network namespace in Linux. I am getting

```
RTNETLINK answers: invalid argument.
```

Kernel version I am using is 4.15.0 from kernel.org

Below is the exact list of commands I am running and associated output

```
$IP link add vrf-red type vrf table 10
$IP netns add foo
$IP link set vrf-red netns foo
RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument
```

Is this not supported? If so, what is the rationale?

Use case: I am trying to setup two PE devices in the same Linux box, so I have a separate netns for each of the PE device. Now I want to add a VRF device to the PE `netns` so later I can run say zebra in the PE `netns` and it would use the VRF that's available in this namespace.

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is indeed not possible to add a VRF interface to a `netns`

Below is the relevant code - (from the kernel sources that I am using - 4.15.0 in `drivers/net/vrf.c` line `1257`)

```
/* don't allow vrf devices to change network namespaces. */
dev->features |= NETIF_F_NETNS_LOCAL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Whilst you can't move VRF interface to a network namespace, you can create in the namespace:

```
ip netns add foo
ip -n foo link add vrf-red type vrf table 10
```